# useNavigate does not replace my dynamic parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

On our project, we were using version 4 of react-router, and we have migrated to version 6.

However, we are encountering an issue that I cannot identify since the change from the useLocation API to useNavigate.

Here's my function:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

import { IProps, IPropsReturn } from './types';

export const useSteppers = ({ steppers, redirectPath }: IProps): IPropsReturn => {
  const { customerOuid, routeFeature, routeTab, step } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const currentStep = step ? parseInt(step) : 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!step || currentStep > steppers.length - 1) {
      navigate(`/customer/${customerOuid}/${routeTab}/${routeFeature}/0`);
    }
  }, [step]);

  const handlePrevStep = () => {
    const prevStep = currentStep - 1;

    if (currentStep === 0) {
      return navigate(-1);
    }
    return navigate(`${prevStep}`, { replace: true });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (triggerPolling: () => void) => {
    const nextStep = currentStep + 1;

    if (currentStep === steppers.length - 1 && redirectPath) {
      if (triggerPolling) {
        return triggerPolling();
      }
      return navigate(redirectPath, { replace: true });
    }

    return navigate(`${nextStep}`, { replace: true });
  };

  return {
    currentStep,
    handlePrevStep,
    handleSubmit,
  };
};
```

The problem is actually here :

```js
return navigate(`${nextStep}`, { replace: true });
```

When the function is executed, the navigate function returns a route :

`localhost:3000/#/customer/123/accounting/chargeCancellation/0/1`

Do you see the problem ? `0/1` I would like only `/1`

Before we migrate to v6 we use :

```js
    const history = useHistory(); 
    return history.replace(`${nextStep}`);
```

Comment: Can you create a demo? Looking at your comment, you might be calling `handleSubmit` incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

According with react-router-dom doc [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.9.0/hooks/use-navigate) you can simply add `../` before your desired path. It will be replace in the route history, so going back will intercept the parent route, depending on how you configured your routes.

In your case try using

`` return navigate(`../${nextStep}`, {replace:true}); ``

I hope it could help you

Comment: We tried this before, with your solution the behavior is : `localhost:3000/#/customer/123/accounting/chargeCancellation/1/1`

It is lightly better but we have a double value at the end

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a *relative* path to navigate to a sibling route:

```js
navigate(`../${prevStep}`, { replace: true });
```

```js
navigate(`../${nextvStep}`, { replace: true });
```

You could also compute the *absolute* path as well:

```js
navigate(
  `/customer/${customerOuid}/${routeTab}/${routeFeature}/${prevStep}`,
  { replace: true }
);
```

```js
navigate(
  `/customer/${customerOuid}/${routeTab}/${routeFeature}/${nextStep}`,
  { replace: true }
);
```